# Quitar valores repetidos de un objeto

Tags: javascript, objeto

```js
function TablaFrecuencia(...aDatos){
    
    var intPosicionArray=0;
    var intContadorRepetidos;
    var aTablaFrecuencia=[];
    
    //ordenar de forma ascendente, luego utilizare
    Array.prototype.sortNumeros=function(){
        return this.sort(
        function(a,b){
            return a.numero - b.numero;//ascendiente
        }
        );
     };
     
    //comprobación de errores y vacíos 
    if(aDatos.length===0){//está vacía
        return aTablaFrecuencia=[];
    }else{
       for (let valoresArrayValores of aDatos){
        intPosicionArray++;
        valoresArrayValores=parseFloat(valoresArrayValores);
        if(isNaN(valoresArrayValores))
            throw "el argumento "+intPosicionArray+" no es numérico";
        } 
    }
    //recorrer los argumentos y ver cuantos hay de cada uno
    for(let i=0; i<aDatos.length;i++){
        intContadorRepetidos=0;//vuelve a 0 para que evalue el siguiente numero del array
        for (let j = 0; j <aDatos.length; j++) {
            if (parseFloat(aDatos[i]) === parseFloat(aDatos[j])) {//minimo entrará una vez
                intContadorRepetidos++;
                //ejemplo: esta recorriendo la array en posicion [i], digamos 0, y comprobando que ese valor este en la misma array en posicion [j], de 0 hasta la longitud del array
            }
        }
        //introducir los datos con las propiedades en la array, mediante push, se introducen al final del array
        aTablaFrecuencia.push({
            numero:parseFloat(aDatos[i]),
            frecuencia: intContadorRepetidos
        });
        intContadorRepetidos=0; //para evaluar el siguiente numero
    }
    
    aTablaFrecuencia.sortNumeros();//ordenar de forma ascendente cuando la array ya esta completamente llena
    //console.log(aTablaFrecuencia);
    return aTablaFrecuencia;//devuelve un array con los numeros introducidos y las frecuencias correspondientes. Los numeros estan ordenados
}
```

Estoy realizando la moda de un array que contiene objetos con propiedad numero y frecuencia,el problema es que tras quedarme con los valores que mas se repiten, dichos valores no se como guardarlos en la array de forma unica. En la array se me esta almacenando los numeros con mayor frecuencia pero de forma repetida. Si el numero 2 se repite 5 veces, se me muestra 5 veces ese numero y no unicamente una vez. Muchas gracias

Os muestro un trozo del código. En él lo que hago es quedarme con los de mayor frecuencia (repetidos) y luego intento quitar los repetidos pero eso ya no funciona. Si es posible me gustaria saber una forma para hacer este filter (que recuerdo que funciona bien) y junto a ese quitar los repetidos. Me estoy volviendo un poco loco. Muchas gracias

```js
function Moda(...aDatos){
//TablaFrecuencia lo que hace es coger los datos pasados y pasar un array de objetos con la propiedad, numero y frecuencia
var aAuxiliar=TablaFrecuencia(...aDatos);
console.log(aAuxiliar);//hasta aqui bien

var intContadorRepetidos=2;//para que se empiece a considerar moda
for (var i = 0; i <aAuxiliar.length; i++) {
    if(aAuxiliar[i].frecuencia>=intContadorRepetidos){
        intContadorRepetidos=aAuxiliar[i].frecuencia; //si aparece un numero 5 veces, la nueva frecuencia a superar será esa
        console.log(intContadorRepetidos);//hasta aqui bien
    }
}
//buscar que numeros tienen la maxima frecuencia, en que posiciones e introducirlos en la array final y que no se repitan
//devolvera el objeto que coincida con la frecuencia que estoy buscando
    
var aModa=[];

  //esto lo que hace es quedarse con los de mayor frecuencia
    aAuxiliar=aAuxiliar.filter(function (obj){ 
            return obj.frecuencia===intContadorRepetidos;
        }); 
        
        for(let variable of aModa){// se repite
            console.log(variable.numero+' '+variable.frecuencia);
        }
        return aModa;
}
```

Comment: ya lo conseguí:var objAuxiliar={};
    for ( var i=0; i <aTablaFrecuencia.length; i++ ){
        objAuxiliar[aTablaFrecuencia[i]["numero"]] = aTablaFrecuencia[i];
    }
    
    aTablaFrecuencia= new Array(); //la pongo a 0 de nuevo para introducirle los NO REPETIDOS
    for (let clave in objAuxiliar ){
        aTablaFrecuencia.push(objAuxiliar[clave]);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aplicá este codigo y retorná `sinRepetir` en lugar de `aModa`.

Creo una nueva variable llamada `sinRepetir` como un objeto Set (conjunto que no permite elementos repetido) del resultado de aplicar la funcion `map` a la variable `aModa`, luego (o mejor dicho antes de todo esto) el Set se convierte en una lista con el spread operator `...` . Este operador es opcional dependiendo del tipo de resultado esperado.

```
var  sinRepetir = [...new Set(aModa.map(item => item))];
```

---

### EDIT: Eliminar duplicados con filter

El método `filter()` devuelve una matriz o vector, con elementos que pasen la condición dada (los que devuelvan true).
Recibe un callback como parámetro, el cual a su vez recibe tres parámetros:

- El item actual del array
- El indice del item actual del array
- El array actual

Supongamos que tenemos el array:

```
var miArray = [1,4,5,1,7,4];
```

Le vamos a aplicar `filter()` a `miArray` de la manera indicada, donde:

`return` es el array de donde vamos a filtrar los elementos sin repetir

`item` es el elemento del array (el primero es 1, el segundo es 4, etc.)

`index` es el índice al que pertenece el elemento (de 0 a 5 en este caso)

```
resultado = miArray.filter((item, index) => {
    return miArray.indexOf(item) === index;
)}
```

Lo que hara la linea `return miArray.indexOf(item) === index;` es lo siguiente:

Una vez parado en un elemento, lo retornara unicamente si **la primer aparicion de este en el array** `(_miArray.indexOf(item)_)` es igual al `index` actual.

Es decir, imagina que en el array `var miArray = [1,4,5,1,7,4];` pasa elemento a elemento:

- Primero verifica el numero 1. El indice es 0, y la primer aparicion del numero 1 es el indice 0. Verdadero, se guarda.
- Luego, verifica numero 4. El indice es 1, y la primer aparicion es en el indice 1. Verdadero, se guarda.
- Lo mismo para el elemento 5 en la posicion 2.
- Cuando llega al elemento 1 en la posicion 3, el indice actual es 3 pero la primer aparicion es en el indice 0, por lo que no se guarda.

Finalmente se obtiene el resultado esperado en la variable `resultado`

Comment: Hay otra forma de hacerlo sin ...new Set. Esto es un trabajo de clase, y esto aun no lo hemos visto. He visto esta forma y otra utilizando self, pero es mejor que no las utilice ya que aun no lo hemos  visto. Pero muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, si no encuentro otra forma acabaré aplicando lo que me has dicho. Muy amable, muchas gracias

Comment: Ah bien, y cuales son las herramientas con las que podes contar?

Comment: Los metodos filter, every, some, map, indexOf, push, includes. Los más basicos supongo. Por eso intente filtrar los datos con el includes() y luego hacer push() pero parece no funcionar. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Bueno, ahi lo resolví con el método filter e indexOf, espero te sirva.

Comment: muchas gracias. Ahora lo intento aplicar. Yo tengo una array que contiene objetos,con dos propiedades numero y frecuencia.Esto que me acabas de explicar funcionaría, no? Muchas gracias, muy amable

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta y mostrar el elemento que quieres filtrar?

Comment: Ya esta editado con todo. Utilizo el metodo TablaFrecuncia, si necesitas el cogido de este me lo dices y te lo paso. Pero ese metodo devuelve un array donde cada casilla es un objeto con la propiedad numero (el que se introduce en la funciona) y la frecuencia (las veces que aparece ese mismo numero en los datos pasados)

Comment: No, lo que quiero es ver como se ve en consola el elemento que queres filtrar, por ejemplo moda = [{1,2},{2,3},{1,5},{4,3}] o moda = [{"valor":1,"frecuencia":2},{"valor":2,"frecuencia":3},{"valor":4,"frecuencia":6},{"valor":2,"frecuencia":2}] , no se si me explico. Es porque quiero probar que el codigo funcione antes de mandar la respuesta

Comment: Soy nuevo aqui, asi que no se como funciona y me estoy volviendo loco. Lo que devuelve es lo siguiente: [{numero:1, frecuencia:2}] y asi sucesivamente

Comment: jaja no pasa nada, si podés hace un console.log del objeto que necesitas filtrar y lo pegas en la pregunta o aca asi te entiendo, yo tambien soy medio nuevo y me interesa responder preguntas e ir investigando porque me ayuda a aprender

Comment: lo intente hacer en la pregunta, pero como en la pregunta tengo puesto la llamada al otro metodo, la console.log da erro. Por eso te lo pongo en la respuesta mejor